# Get database value from generated PHP-HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, database

I have been struggling with this for some time and cannot get it to work.

I have a form that sends a request to a php page. The php page returns the records
and outputs them as an html table. Certain fields in the table have a radio button, so that
the user can select that value. That value should be stored in an area, like a cart,
on the page. Here is what I have:

PHP page snippet:

```
while (oci_fetch($stmt)){
echo  "<tr>\n"
    . "<td class='v1'><input type='radio' name='price' value='STANDARD' id='rbt'>" . oci_result($stmt, 'STANDARD') . "</td>\n"
    . "<td class='v2'><input type='radio' name='price' value='PREMIUM' id='rbt2'>" . oci_result($stmt, 'PREMIUM') . "</td>\n"
    ....
    . "</tr>\n";
```

}

HTML code:

```
<td class='v1'><input type='radio' name='price' value='STANDARD' id='rbt'>798,4</td>
<td class='v2'><input type='radio' name='price' value='PREMIUM' id='rbt2'>965,87</td>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           $("#rbt, #rbt2").click(function(){
              alert($('input[name=fare]:checked').val());
           });
       });
```

This only shows an alert, which is not the goal.

So the question is: When a value, i.e. 798,4, is selected, it must be stored in the cart for a later calculation. Would JQuery solve this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: homework assignment? but to answer your question, jQuery could solve this if applied properly.

Comment: An example of how to implement this would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: A jsfiddle showing a working copy with what you tried so far would be nice! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           $("#rbt, #rbt2").click(function(){
          //alert($('input[name=fare]:checked').val()); // this value come whcih is  "STANDARD"

//so use
alert($(this).closest("td").text()); //alert   798,4

   //to store in a div html use html();
  $("divid").html($(this).closest("td").text());
           });
         });
```

Comment: Yes, this shows the value as an alert. But the goal is to show this value, i.e., in a div. Thanks!